# Can't drop an index in postgres Heroku - receive ERROR: index "ix_public_jobs_next_run_time" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, heroku, indexing, drop

I have a table in Heroku Postgres (Hobby tier) with a "jobs" table. I am using PGAdmin to view and work with the database.

If I view the dependents tab for the "jobs" table, I can see that an index exists "public.ix_public_jobs_next_run_time".

From the query tool, I run the query "DROP INDEX public.ix_public_jobs_next_run_time;" and get the following error:

ERROR:  index "ix_public_jobs_next_run_time" does not exist
SQL state: 42704

Why can't I drop this index?

*Background: I am using SQLAlchemy ORM to db upgrade my postgres database to modify some tables.  The db upgrade command fails when it tries to drop the index.  I used the steps above to recreate this error.*

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT quote_ident(relname) FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE '%next%' AND relkind = 'i' ;`?

Comment: It returns: ix_public_jobs_next_run_time

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you set a `search_path` that does not include `public`. Then you have to name the schema explicitly:

```
DROP INDEX public.ix_public_jobs_next_run_time;
```

Another option is of course that you connected to the wrong database when you tried to drop the index.